# Need pointers to deep learning tutorials

Tags: machine-learning, references, deep-learning, deep-belief-networks

I'm looking for good study material about deep belief networks, with particular emphasis to classification and feature extraction tasks for non-image data.

I don't seem to find a great deal about it. Either the material I come across is too much high level, or too much into the detail.

Any recommendation?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what is "too ... high a level"? How shall we assess what level would be suitable?

Comment: Knock yourself out: http://jmozah.github.io/links/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a shopping list question.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best tutorials you can get on Deep Learning is the class of Prof. Nando de Freitas at Oxford Uni. which is available at https://www.youtube.com/user/ProfNandoDF. It covers all the latest deep learning architectures and even dives into Torch7 implementations (state-of-the-art tool in DL).

Finally, one of the beauties of DL is that the same models can apply to a wide range of input data, so, image models can be applied in many other disciplines.